# Rails - How to add validation on callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to add validation on a before_validation model filter. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

--
EDIT
I didn't express myself correctly. I need to add validation on a callback like that:

```
validate :check_length

def check_length
 if my_conditional
     validates_length_of   :name, :minimum => 5
 else
     validates_length_of   :name, :minimum => 7
end
```

Comment: Validation before validation is a conceptual concept

Comment: Are you getting errors? What happens if you add the :message option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to create a method and call it from the callback

```
    before_validation :run_this_check


    def run_this_check
    ##run your validation
       errors.add(:key, "This is your error message")
    end
```

or if the validation is not dealing with an attribute (or field)

```
   def run_this_check
     errors.add_to_base('error message')
   end
```

Comment: Just to add, if the validation error has nothing to do with a single attribute on the record, an alternative method of adding the error is: `self.errors[:base] << "The error message."`

Comment: You can also use scoped messages by passing a symbol as message. So `errors.add(:column, :invalid)` will lookup `activerecord.errors.models.MODEL.attributes.ATTRIBUTE.invalid` in the locale files

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
class X < ActiveRecord

  validates_length_of   :name, :minimum => 5 if my_condition
  validates_length_of   :name, :minimum => 7 unless my_condition

end
```

what's the condition?